# OpenCV Matrix Constructor Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram

I get a segmentation fault when executing

```
cv::Mat hist=cv::Mat(1,no_patterns,CV_32SC1,cv::Scalar(0));
```

Where no_patterns=256

However it doesn't crash on the first execution of the function but on the second.

If it is of any importance getHistFromLBP and histAVG are declared static in their class.

Context:

getHistFromLBP function

```
cv::Mat LBP::getHistFromLBP(const cv::Mat& lbp_mat,unsigned no_patterns, bool normed)
{   
    // It crashes here 
    cv::Mat hist=cv::Mat(1,no_patterns,CV_32SC1,cv::Scalar(0));


for (unsigned i=0;i<no_patterns;i++)
    hist.at<int32_t>(1,i)=0;

for (int i=0;i<lbp_mat.rows;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<lbp_mat.cols;j++)
    {
        uint32_t bin;

        switch (lbp_mat.type())
        {
            case CV_8UC1: bin=static_cast<uint32_t>(lbp_mat.at<uint8_t>(i,j)); break;
            case CV_16UC1: bin=static_cast<uint32_t>(lbp_mat.at<uint16_t>(i,j)); break;
            case CV_32SC1: bin=static_cast<uint32_t>(lbp_mat.at<int32_t>(i,j)); break;
        }

        hist.at<uint32_t>(1,bin)+=1;
    }

if (normed)
{
    unsigned long sum=0;
    for (int i=0;i<hist.cols;i++)
    {
        sum += hist.at<uint32_t>(1, i);
    }
    std::cout << "Found sum = " << sum << std::endl;
    for (int i=0;i<hist.cols;i++)
    {
        std::cout<< "Working on normalizing i= " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Hist(i) = " << hist.at<uint32_t>(1,i) << std::endl;
        hist.at<float>(i) = hist.at<uint32_t>(1, i) * 1.0 / (sum + std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon());

    }
}


return hist;
}
```

The function that calls function that retrieves the histograms.

```
if (sliding_window_frames.window_full())
{
    // We can calculate the AFF hist and the CF-AFF Chi Square distance
    std::vector<cv::Mat>* cf_mat=sliding_window_frames.getCFMat();
    std::vector<cv::Mat>* front_mat=sliding_window_frames.getFrontMat();
    std::vector<cv::Mat>* back_mat=sliding_window_frames.getBackMat();

    std::vector<double> tmp_diffs;
    for (unsigned i=0;i<cf_mat->size();i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Current block analyzed is: " << i << std::endl;
        // This call of getHistFromLBP executes OK
        cv::Mat histCF=lbp_extractor->getHistFromLBP((*cf_mat)[i],256,normed_histograms);
        // This call fails with a segmentation fault
        cv::Mat histFront=lbp_extractor->getHistFromLBP((*front_mat)[i],256,normed_histograms);
        cv::Mat histBack=lbp_extractor->getHistFromLBP((*back_mat)[i],256,normed_histograms);
        std::cout << "Found Histograms " << std::endl;
        cv::Mat histAFF=lbp_extractor->histAvg(histFront,histBack,normed_histograms);
        std::cout << "Found Hist AFF " << std::endl;
        double chisquared=lbp_extractor->getChiSquaredDistanceFromHist(histCF,histAFF,normed_histograms);
        std::cout << "Found chi squared " << std::endl;
        tmp_diffs.push_back(chisquared);
        std::cout << "Pushed chi squared " << std::endl;
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is also the GDB backtrace when it seg-faulted:

```
#0  0x00007fffefc1bfff in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007fffefc1d42a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007fffefc59c00 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=2, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7fffefd4ed78 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n")
at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007fffefc5ffc6 in malloc_printerr (action=3, str=0x7fffefd4b8be "corrupted size vs. prev_size", ptr=<optimized out>, ar_ptr=<optimized out>)
at malloc.c:5049
#4  0x00007fffefc603b8 in malloc_consolidate (av=av@entry=0x7fffeff80b00 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:4221
#5  0x00007fffefc61dfa in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7fffeff80b00 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=1136) at malloc.c:3488
#6  0x00007fffefc6293e in _int_memalign (av=av@entry=0x7fffeff80b00 <main_arena>, alignment=alignment@entry=64, bytes=bytes@entry=1024)
at malloc.c:4459
#7  0x00007fffefc6435f in _mid_memalign (alignment=64, bytes=1024, address=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:3158
#8  0x00007fffefc65fef in __posix_memalign (memptr=0x7fffffffbd38, alignment=<optimized out>, size=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:5071
#9  0x00007ffff57e967b in cv::fastMalloc(unsigned long) () at /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.3
#10 0x00007ffff5930ae6 in cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int) () at /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.3
#11 0x000055555556995e in cv::Mat::create(int, int, int) (this=0x7fffffffbff0, _rows=1, _cols=256, _type=4)
at /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:784
#12 0x00005555555698b5 in cv::Mat::Mat(int, int, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&) (this=0x7fffffffbff0, _rows=1, _cols=256, _type=4, _s=...)
at /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:420
#13 0x0000555555568ccf in LBP::getHistFromLBP(cv::Mat const&, unsigned int, bool) (lbp_mat=..., no_patterns=256, normed=true) at ../src/lbp.cpp:162
#14 0x0000555555572760 in RM_Analyzer::addNewFrame(cv::Mat, bool) (this=0x7fffffffc490, img=..., is_lbp_img=false) at ../src/rm_analyzer.cpp:86
#15 0x00005555555721ff in RM_Analyzer::analyzeVid() (this=0x7fffffffc490) at ../src/rm_analyzer.cpp:25
#16 0x0000555555577241 in main(int, char const**) (argc=15, argv=0x7fffffffe0b8) at ../bin_src/main.cpp:198
```

Linked libraries in Makefile:
LIBSLANDMARK=-lFaceAnalyser -lLandmarkDetector -ltbb -ldlib -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
LIBSOPENCV=-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_highgui  -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs

OpenCV Version used:3.3 (I wrote a c++ file that writes major and minor version since i wasn't sure if it was 3.2 or 3.3)

Comment: OpenCV version? Compiler? Debug&Release? x64/x86? IDE? Show includes and linked libs

Comment: @Miki According to stacktrace, I would guess: x64.

Comment: @Miki Added The linked libraries, and version. Laptop is X86_64 Debian based linux, IDE shouldn't be relevant but i used sublime now switched to CLion.

Comment: the folder of the libraries? -L option

Comment: Generally I'd start by using an tool to look for memory corruption. Options are clang's address sanitizer (asan) or valgrind. (Clang has other sanitizers as well.)

Comment: @Miki /usr/local/include I have installed the opencv libraries and called the linker so that i can use them from program so no -L is required.

Comment: You are running in debug or in release?

Comment: @ZalmanStern what do you suspect it is? I suspected it was cause the function was static - changed so that i call new on matrix creation so i get a pointer that i can free when im finished. But same efect seg. fault on 2nd call.

Comment: @Miki Release though i have Debug compiled and ready to go.

Comment: Well, it seems that you have everything setup correctly...

Comment: Likely something is corrupting memory -- writing off the end of a buffer, etc. Could be a lot of things and you have not posted all the code and even if you did, it is a bad use of this site to ask people to debug that much code. A tool for finding these errors has a good chance of telling you exactly what is going wrong quickly and should be a standard part of how you work. I.e. used before posting to Stack Overflow. Sometimes such tools don't work for various reasons but they are getting pretty good.

Comment: Thanks @ZalmanStern Literally just ran valgrind and immediately it detected a bad write.  Namely each hist.at<..> should be of index 0 not 1 since i created a 1D array. And since i write at<>(1,..) it has a mem corruption.